# Insert data in the mysql database with background thread in grails application

Tags: multithreading, spring, grails, asynchronous

Hi I have grails web application where users can save the data by importing the data from a excel or csv file and my application parses the data and saves them in database, but if there are too many records like 40,000 it's taking more time.

So I what I wanted to do is run this task in the background and notify users after the task is done through an email, so that users don't have to sit there ideally and can work on some other task.

Can you suggest me a way where I can save the records in database using background thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch the long running task in a separate thread, using the `@Async`annotation, see the documentation for it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html):

> 25.5.2 The @Async Annotation
>
> The @Async annotation can be provided on a method so that invocation
>   of that method will occur asynchronously. In other words, the caller
>   will return immediately upon invocation and the actual execution of
>   the method will occur in a task that has been submitted to a Spring
>   TaskExecutor. In the simplest case, the annotation may be applied to a
>   void-returning method.

This is a code example of how to use it:

```
@Async
void doSomething() {
    // this will be executed asynchronously
}
```

To give a ETL (Extract Transform Load) like structure to the batch, have a look a spring batch. This is an example of how to read a CSV and upload it to the database using spring batch - [CSV File Upload](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-csv-file-to-database/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Quartz Plugin**, and then create a Job that runs on demand and does the inserting for you without blocking the users.  Link to plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/quartz